# Meaning of "the awesome sweep of the scenery"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms

What's the meaning of this statement:

"**the awesome sweep of the scenery**"?

I know meaning of **awesome**, **sweep**, **scenery** but I can't understand this sentence at all!

Is it an idiom?

Comment: Does *the amazing expanse of the view* make sense?

Comment: The noun definition **5** for [**sweep**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sweep) says "A long, typically curved stretch of road, river, or land. *We could see a wide sweep of country perhaps a hundred miles across*." This makes sense in the context of scenery. It is always worth checking a dictionary even if you think you know the meaning of a word.

Comment: @Davo Thank you, now it makes sense

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you